# How can I load a packrat managed package from any working directory

Tags: r, r-package, packrat

I built a package using [packrat](https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/) to deal with dependencies versions.

```
@nyzls65c:~/private/research$ tree -L 1 -a sp.util  
sp.util                                                     
|-- .Rbuildignore                                           
|-- .Rhistory                                               
|-- .Rprofile                                               
|-- .Rproj.user                                             
|-- DESCRIPTION                                             
|-- NAMESPACE                                               
|-- R                                                       
|-- Read-and-delete-me                                      
|-- man                                                     
|-- packrat                                                 
|-- sp.util.Rproj
```

When I start `R` from the package path `~/private/research/sp.util` I can see that packrat deals with my libraries:

```
@nyzls65c:~/private/research/sp.util$ Rscript -e ".libPaths()"                       
WARNING: ignoring environment value of R_HOME                                                
[1] "~/private/research/sp.util/packrat/lib/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu/3.3.0"
[2] "~/private/research/sp.util/packrat/lib-ext"                          
[3] "~/private/research/sp.util/packrat/lib-R"
```

When I start from anywhere else

```
@nyzls65c:~/private/research$ Rscript -e ".libPaths()"        
WARNING: ignoring environment value of R_HOME                         
NULL                                                                  
[1] "~/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3"      
[2] "/usr/lib64/R/library"                                            
[3] "/usr/share/R/library"
```

I guess what `packrat` does is loading the `.Rprofile` file it generates in the package directory and setup the `.libPaths()`.

The problem is that then when I do `library(sp.util)`, unless I am in the right directory the wrong packages will be loaded. (I tested by doing `sessionInfo()`  while starting from within `/sp.util` and without and quite logically the packages in `Depends` are not the same)

What I want to do is use `Rscript /path/script.r`, load `sp.util` within `script.r` and have the correct (ie packrat-local ones) dependencies loaded. I do not want to have to start Rscript from a given path.

Do I need to set the `libPaths()` myself with `R_LIB_USER` to do it ?

And say I need multiple packages using `packrat` is it even a viable option to do the above ?

Comment: I'm having the same issues at the moment, any luck?

Comment: nope, this question is left hanging

Comment: Depending on your use case my current plan is to use `miniCRAN` package to build a locally managed repo on the network I am deploying over. This may be suitable for you depending on your use case.

Comment: well mini cran does not handle several package versions which appears like a must have for me...

Comment: It will handle a range of different packages, I think, I'll update this if I find out otherwise if you mean I need a copy of data.table 1.9.4 AND 1.9.6 on access depending on R version on the local machine then perhaps theres a clue in this slide 8? http://www.slideshare.net/RevolutionAnalytics/through-the-firewall-with-minicran Suggests using a folder per R version.

Comment: r version is not the issue, package version is, you cannot have 1.9,2.0,2.1 for the same R

Comment: From your description, it sounds like this may be blurring the lines between the `packrat` environment (i.e., when you start R in the `sp.util` directory), and the advertised dependencies of the package, as defined by `Depends:` or `Imports:` in the `DESCRIPTION` file. If you need to "hold-back" dependent packages to a specific non-current version, perhaps you should use an equality, such as `Depends: pkgname (== 0.1)` (whereas most of the time, it is an inequality, `pkgname (>= 0.1)`).